# Which authentication gem/plugin should I use for Rails 3 running on CouchDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, couchdb

I'm building a Rails 3 application on CouchDB (using SimplyStored gem) and I'd like to use some existing gem/plugin for authentication, instead of building it from scratch.

Problem is, I can't find anything that works smoothly for CouchDB, everything assumes that you're running on ActiveRecord. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using [CouchRest_Model](http://github.com/shenoudab/devise_couch).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into it and I'm probably going to switch to Couchrest_Model (I'm also considering couchrails gem), its better for my purposes than SimplyStored, especially in Rails 3.

That doesn't answer the question though - is there a quick way to implement validation on CouchDB without all this ActiveRecord / ActiveModel hassle? I guess not, I'll need to "simulate" ActiveRecord behaviour (through ActiveModel) for specific authentication gem.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I've used heavily customized [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) gem for authentication. It's very flexible, so you're able to use it even for NoSQL database - but you have to rewrite most of the functionality (not by monkey-patching, all within limits of Clearance customization), which probably takes more effort that to write whole authentication from scratch. While a good-enough solution, but I'm sure there better ones.

Comment: do you still using Clearance customized for CouchRest Model?

Comment: I think so. I haven't seen that project for a long time, but I think that in the end I've used CouchRest_Model and Clearance. But that was a long time ago, I'm sure there are better options available today.

Comment: it seems that this better options are hidden heheheh